# Sliding animation when hiding/showing a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs, top and bottom. Both divs have dynamic height, the top div will show or hide depending on a variable.

I would like to add in a sliding animation to the top div when showing or hiding, but the bottom div should stick with the top div and slide with it too.

```js
var hide = true;
var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
var topdiv = document.getElementById("topdiv");

trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (hide) {
   topdiv.classList.add('hide');
  } else {
   topdiv.classList.remove('hide');
  }
  hide = !hide;
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}


.top {
  background: #999;
}

.body {
  background: #555;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="topdiv" class="top hide">
<p>Top</p>
</div>
<div class="body">
<p>Body</p>
<button id="trigger">
Trigger
</button>
</div>
```

I tried adding transform animations, but the effect is only applied to the top div while the bottom div remains unanimated.

```
@keyframes topDivAnimate {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    to {
        transform:translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: So do you also want the second div to get hidden, just like the first one?

Comment: Nope just the first one, like the example above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use CSS transition rather than animation. I've found it easiest to do by animating the lower div rather than the upper one, and changing its position so that it covers the top one (or, of course, not). See demonstration below, I've made as minimal changes as I could to the CSS and JS:

```js
var cover = true;
var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
var bottomdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0];

trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (cover) {
   bottomdiv.classList.add('cover');
  } else {
   bottomdiv.classList.remove('cover');
  }
  cover = !cover;
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}


.top {
  background: #999;
}

.body {
  background: #555;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.cover {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="topdiv" class="top hide">
<p>Top</p>
</div>
<div class="body">
<p>Body</p>
<button id="trigger">
Trigger
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer but it won't work as easy due to dynamic heights for both the body and the top div. I found an even smaller solution by animating `max-height` of the top div, setting it to 0 when hidden and a maximum reasonable height when not hidden. The animation lags a little when there's a big difference between the max-height and the actual height of the top-div but in my case it works good!

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking something like this? Then please try this:

```js
var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
var topdiv = document.getElementById("topdiv");

trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if ($('#topdiv').css('display') == 'none') {
   $(topdiv).slideDown();
  } else {
   $(topdiv).slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}


.top {
  display: none;
  background: #999;
}

.body {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topdiv" class="top hide">
<p>Top</p>
</div>
<div class="body">
<p>Body</p>
<button id="trigger">
Trigger
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no indication that the OP is using, or intends to use, jQuery. Of course it's a fine solution, but jQuery definitely isn't needed just for something like this.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I am someone who is usually against using jQuery, but in this case, it makes sense to use jQuery to solve this simply and in a few lines of code. Compare this jQuery solution to mine (which uses pure JS and the Animate.css library).

Comment: well see my answer for a working solution involving only pure CSS and vanilla JS, and very few changes to the OP's code :-) [PS I'm not against using jQuery, I think it's great for a lot of use cases, but I wouldn't include it just to use `slideDown`/`slideUp` on one element]

Comment: @RobinZigmond You can see the animation effect difference in both the solution. In my solution, the sliding effect is better with slideDown/slideUp. That is the main reason to prefer JQuery in this type of cases.

Comment: I don't really see much difference in the result - other than the bottom div isn't quite perfectly lined up in mine when it reaches the top. I haven't tried to fix that but I guess it's due to the padding, and can think of several relatively easy ways to fix it. And i went with basic CSS and JS because that's what the OP was already using. PS if there is a noticeable difference in how the animation works, that's easy to customise in the CSS if you want to: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if that's the effect you wanted. It uses the [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library so you'll need to link that in your `<head></head>`

```
function animateCSS(element, animationName, callback) {
    const node = document.querySelector(element)
    node.classList.add('animated', animationName)

    function handleAnimationEnd() {
        node.classList.remove('animated', animationName)
        node.removeEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd)

        if (typeof callback === 'function') callback()
    }

    node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd)
}

var hide = false;
var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
var topdiv = document.getElementById("topdiv");

trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!hide) {
    topdiv.classList.remove('hide');
    animateCSS('.body', 'slideInDown');
    animateCSS('#topdiv', 'slideInDown');
  } else {
    animateCSS('#topdiv', 'slideOutUp', function() {
      topdiv.classList.add('hide');
    })
    animateCSS('.body', 'slideOutUp');
  }
  hide = !hide;
});
```

[Working Codepen demo of my solution](https://codepen.io/merkur0/pen/eoLMYV)

[Here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)'s some more explanation on how to use the Animate.css library.